# Can't submit form on checkbox click with jQuery + Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, jquery-ui

I'm trying to have each form submit when the corresponding checkbox is clicked. Right now I can see that the click registers, but no form is submitted. Code is as follows:

```
- @current_agency.tasks.active.each do |task|
    = form_for task do |f|
        %tr
            %td
                = f.check_box :completed, :class => "taskCheckbox"
            %td
                = task.name
            %td
                = task.due_at.to_date.strftime( "%m-%d-%Y" )
        = submit_tag 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

jQuery:

```
$('.taskCheckbox').on('change', function() { $(this).closest('form').submit(); });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work... something sounds off.

Try debugging `closest('form')`?

You can also explicitly get the form of an input: `$(this.form).submit()` rather than searching.